# Execute binaries / tests on host that are built by non-host toolchain

Tags: gcc, bazel, toolchain

**Scenario:**

- We would like to build our sources by an external / hermetic toolchain so all includes, libs and tools from the host are ignored
- To do so, a new toolchain is introduced to Bazel-Configuration. >>> working well
- Using `-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN/%{runtime_library_search_directories}/...` the relative path from the binary to the libs that should be loaded on runtime gets defined >>> works quite well
- When doing `bazel run` the Binary is executed but the host's LD is being used
- To get rid of this a wrapper (written in Bash) is injected using `--run_under`. >>> dirty workaround

**Problem:**

`--run_under` could only be used once. We also need this option to execute tests within a specific environment and so this option is not the way of choice for us. IMHO it's also a bit dirty workaround.

We also tried to use `-Wl,--dynamic-linker=<<PATH_TO_LD>>`. But we were not able to get neither a  relative nor an absolute path to LD when linking the executable.

**Questions:**

Is there ...

- ... any way to get the absolute/relative path to LD when linking?
- ... any other way of running a binary on Host using a toolchain?
- ... a possibility to do sandboxing/chroot so the correct LD of the toolchain is being used automatically?

**Sidenotes:**

- Bazel 1.1.0 is used
- the toolchain is GCC8 build from sources
- the host is an Ubuntu 18.04.1 image running in docker

Comment: @Vertexwahn I'm in your same situation, could you ellaborate on how you get "Using -Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN/%{runtime_library_search_directories}/..." to work?